# Flask router from other file

Tags: python, flask, routes, attributeerror

I'm now structuring Flask application like below.

```
myserver
- server.py
- myapp
-- urls.py
-- models.py
-- views.py
-- consts.py
```

And my codes are here.

**server.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

# Flask App
application = Flask(__name__)

# SQLAlchemy
application.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:./local.db"
db = SQLAlchemy(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(debug=True)
```

**urls.py**

```
from server import application
from . import views

@application.route('/')
def version():
    return views.version()
```

But when i run server.py and open http://localhost:5000/ server says `404 Not Found`.

So I searched on stackoverflow, I found some descriptions about `Blueprint`. And I make blueprint named app like `app = Blueprint('app', __name__)` and register it from server.py But I got `AttributeError: module 'urls' has no attribute 'app'` .

How can i define url routers in other file?

Comment: you're calling 'app' but python has no idea what 'app' is. did you forget to also add an import for 'app'? can you post the updated code?

Comment: @FuzzyAmi I also add this line in `server.py` `from myapp import urls` and registerd blueprint urls.app

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here example with `Blueprint`. Structure of files:

```
/project_folder
   server.py
   urls.py
   urls2.py
```

server.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from urls import urls_blueprint
from urls2 import urls2_blueprint


app = Flask(__name__)
# register routes from urls
app.register_blueprint(urls_blueprint)
# we can register routes with specific prefix
app.register_blueprint(urls2_blueprint, url_prefix='/urls2')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

urls.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint

urls_blueprint = Blueprint('urls', __name__,)


@urls_blueprint.route('/')
def index():
    return 'urls index route'
```

urls2.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint
urls2_blueprint = Blueprint('urls2', __name__,)


@urls2_blueprint.route('/')
def index():
    return 'urls2 index route'
```

Run server and open `http://localhost:5000/` and `http://localhost:5000/urls2/`.

Hope this helps.